# terraform can't see object variable

Tags: variables, terraform

I have this variable.tf including the followgin:

```
variable "eks_workers" { 
    type = object({
        backend = object({
            instance_type = string
            instance_count = string
            disk_size = string
        })
    })
}
```

Then i pass the -var-file which includes:

```
    "eks_workers": {
        "backend": {
            "instance_type": "t2.micro",
            "instance_count": "1",
            "disk_size": "40"
        },
        "proxy": {
            "instance_type": "t2.micro",
            "instance_count": "1",
            "disk_size": "40"
        },
        "other": {
            "instance_type": "t2.micro",
            "instance_count": "2",
            "disk_size": "40"
        }
    }
```

Terraform complains with:

```
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│ 
│   on ../../modules/eks/main.tf line 26, in module "eks":
│   26:       instance_type                 = var.eks_workers.backend.instance_type
│ 
│ An input variable with the name "eks_workers" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "eks_workers" {}
│ block.
╵
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are using modules, are you declaring that variable on module level as well ?  What is the content of  `../../modules/eks/main.tf` look like ?

Answer (score 0):

As @aashitvyas pointed out, i wasn't requiring the variable *in* the module's variables.tf, only on the root module.

Thanks!